# System.Diagnostic.Process-command Invocation issue in non english OS

Tags: system.diagnostics

I have implementation where I run an *.EXE through the command prompt using `System.Diagnostic.Process`.
 This works perfectly fine in English OS. However, to support multilingual- I have changed OS display language to French. When I run the same code, it does not do anything. However NO ERROR/EXCEPTION.However, Non English does not do anything (command does not seems to be executed).

Below is the sample code I used,

```
Process pdfProcess = new Process();
StreamWriter writer;
StreamReader reader;

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd");

info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
info.WorkingDirectory = exePath; //Path where Invoke exe located
pdfProcess.StartInfo = info;
pdfProcess.Start();

writer = pdfProcess.StandardInput;
reader = pdfProcess.StandardOutput;
writer.AutoFlush = true;
writer.WriteLine(command);

writer.Close();
string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The issue is the file name. In non-English languages, special characters are getting added to the file name which is not getting executed by above code. For example:

> command = MyEXE.exe "C:\Sin título_ Bloc de notas.txt"

If you see above (Spanish), "í" text is causing the issue. If I remove it them command gets executed.

Anyone has solution how to resolve it?

Comment: it's terminal encoding problem.

Comment: Check out the final message on [this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855675/process-standardinput-encoding-problem

Comment: I tried with the encoding, NO LUCK... Its adding special chars.                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pdfProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream, Encoding.);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pdfProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream, Encoding.Default);

Comment: I have found a workaround with Windows API to get short file name