# How send string into a process with UTF-8 encoding using stdin with C#?

Tags: c#, utf-8, console-application, stdin

I need to send a string using `stdin` into a process using UTF-8 encoding. I do this:

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("process.exe", "");

info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = false;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);

string stringToSend = "человек";
byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringToSend);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);

//But how do I send it now?
//process.StandardInput.WriteLine(stringToSend);    //Replaces all non-ASCII chars with ????
```

but what the process receives is ???? instead of non-English characters.

PS. The Cyrillic word is just to illustrate the example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [process.standardInput encoding problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855675/process-standardinput-encoding-problem)

Comment: The first answer at Alvin's link should solve your problem

Comment: If I use `StreamWriter` the first character received by the process.exe becomes ?. Why is that?

Comment: @alldayremix: The first two characters that the process.exe receives are `ff fe`. Why so? Is there any way to remove them?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, ff fe is the BOM that means "what follows is UTF-8". Incidentally, are you sure that is what your process expects? I would have thought it more likely that it expects PCS-2 if not ASCII.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Yes, it is a BOM. Although not for UTF-8, but for Unicode-16 that my process converted from UTF-8 BOM. I guess, I can handle it in that process since I know what that is. Thanks.